# How do I control an MMC snap-in using PHP (or any other scripting language)?

Tags: php, windows, scripting, mmc, snap-in

I know that you can control an MMC snap-in using the [MMC 2.0 Automation Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa815049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I have not researched its capabilities, but I know that it is used with any of the .NET languages, (Visual C#, VB etc.)

I would like to know if there is any method that can control an MMC snap-in using a scripting language such as PHP, Python or Perl. I specifically would like to know if there is a method that will work with PHP, since the tool I'm building is written in PHP.

In relation to this is my next question. Does anyone know of a library/tool/extension for PHP or any other scripting language that can be used to control and automation Windows' GUI interface control? I ask the MMC question first and separately since I know that the MMC has different issues that prevent some automation tools from working with it. If there is a GUI automation tool that works with a scripting language that works with the MMC, that would be appreciated.

Comment: You can possibly use one of the [Windows API extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.windows.php), w32api or COM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get any .NET object you want into PHP with the [`DOTNET`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) class. This should give you access to whatever you need to do with the MMC.

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking with regards to the Windows GUI, but I shall provide you with a link to [WinBinder](http://winbinder.org/) anyway, in case that helps.

Comment: Ultimately I went with the AutoIT tool. I wrote a script in AutoIT that does it and I just have PHP make system calls to the script